# how do I install windows 10 alongside with ubuntu16.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, gparted, windows-10

I am currently using Xenial and I love it. But still I would like to dual-boot my machine with windows 10. I have been trying to shrink the ubuntu partition to get back unallocated space and then create a partition for windows. But, I am unable to do that through GParted. Could someone please guide me through the process of partitioning and the steps after that to fully install windows 10 on my machine. 
I already have the windows 10 package downloaded. Thank you
Please note that I am a newbie and have really less experience :)

Comment: Did you encrypt whole disk by LUKS?

Comment: @PKM Sorry, but I have no idea what that is!

Comment: Did you check option to encrypt your drive in Ubuntu installation?

Comment: @PKM I dont remember :(

Comment: Do you get screen like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lgRlo.jpg) when you are booting Ubuntu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45214/discussion-between-pkm-and-hedwig).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a bootable Software Like partition wizard or ease us tool ...which can be used to create unallocated disk... (Download.iso and burn into pendrive) after unallocating disk..make a new partition of NTFS format only...again make bootable disk of win 10.iso ,boot and install as regular process..since u r installing win10 after Ubuntu... windows bootloader will overwrite grub and Ubuntu will not be booted...to solve that problem Ubuntu boot-repair program can be used to restore grub and menu will be given to choose in between Ubuntu and window boot loader :) that's it..

Comment: Make sure u follow tutorials on how to use ease us partition in bootable mode ... failure may lead to various problems

Comment: Ubuntu-boot_repair has seperate thread on stack overflow search for it :)

Comment: Better u install Ubuntu after windows ..that way will be safe

Comment: Wont this make me lose all my data

Comment: Make sure u back it up..in some external disk.. since u r installing windows after Ubuntu.. chances of loosing data is more...i have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside win10..so no data lost

Comment: Similar thread is live in home section..search for grub repair after windows installation

Answer (score -1):

here i got a better idea.
1,buy a usb-portable-ssd 
2,make a Win to Go disk on it (win8&&win10),using windows of cause
  or use Wintousb to create this disk.
3,when you wanna use Mswindows, plug it on, it will install drivers&&update itself, just like normal windows.Or you can install it yourself.

have fun @_@